# Como desativar a rolagem horizontal no iphone

Tags: css, mobile, html-meta-tag

Fiz alguns testes em alguns dispositivos e percebi que no iphone tem um scroll horizontal.
Eu ja verifiquei a largura da tela, aparentemente esta ok. O mesmo não acontece em celulares Android.
Estou usando a meta tag abaixo.

```
 `<meta content="minimum-scale=1.0, width=device-width, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport" />`
```

e mesmo assim esse scroll horizontal continua.

Alguém sabe o que pode ser?

Answer (score 0):

vai no css, na tag de container ou algo assim (nao sei como esta seu css)

e acrescente

```
overflow-x:hidden;
```

e coloque tambem com os prefixos :D (webkit,moz,o,ms,etc...)

*acentos no meu teclado nao estao funcionando

Comment: overflow-x:none; não existe, acho que quis dizer overflow-x:hidden rs, eu já tenho um overflow-x:hidden na tag body.

Comment: isso :D eu esqueci, faz muito tempo que nao uso o overflow :D

Comment: Tenta adicionar ele no elemento que ta ultrapassando a tela